# Rails, devise and android.. I want the android app be remain logged in

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Here is what I'm thinking about rails server and android. Please let me know if following steps make sense.

At first, when the android app is launched for the first time, user will type in his/her email address and password.

Then, the app will request to authenticate the user to the rails server, and the server will answer back with token (in token authentication).

The app stores the token and attach the token for subsequent requests. (example : http://myServerUrl.com/books/list?auth_token:xxxx ) And the server will check if the token exists is user table and then send credential data back to the app in JSON format.

My questions are,

- For the first time, when there is a request to server with email address and password in HTML body (in case of POST), is it secure? If the user uses wifi, the whole plain text will be exposed to the public. Is there any secure way to send email and password to the server? Is SSL or assymmetric crypto or HTTPS needed?
- After receiving the auth token from the server, the app will attach that token for sebsequent requests. In other words, the auth token will be exposed as a plain text as well. Is there any secure way to make requests? If someone dumps the one full request and send it to the server, how can server know if it is a valid request?

Since I'm farely new to ror and android apps, any help will release my pain greatly.

Comment: one thing solves all your problems. use https for all connections :).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out...

First, android app need to sign in with email and password.
Server will response back with the auth token.

App will access credential data with the token but the request should be sent as HTTPS.

Jav_Rock wrote the comment that all connections be handled in HTTPS.
I plan to test whether HTTPS connections give reasonable speed when compared with HTTP.
If response time matters, HTTPS might slow down the app.

I will post again after I test HTTPS.